# Gigya RaaS fails when API key is changed

Tags: gigya

I'm using Gigya's Java SDK for RaaS and it was working fine with one API key. Now, I changed it to a new API key with the same Partner ID and Secret Key, the service fails. Any ideas on what else needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to leave a comment:

Can you post a portion of your code, where you are constructing the request? There are very few APIs that require a partner ID, so I am thinking that there is an issue in your parameters.

Assuming that the new API key is associated with the same secret, it should work, assuming you have RaaS activated for both API keys.